# use of SVN as a repository with maven

Tags: maven, svn, tortoisesvn, maven-3

I have to use SVN as a repository for some of the JAR's that I am using in my application.
I have configured my pom.xml like this

```
               <repository>
                <id>repo.pu</id>
                <name>repo.pu</name>
                <url>http://SVNUsername:SVNPassword@BaseURL/Proj_U%20Code/Source%20Code/Jars</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
```

There are white spaces in my folder names and I cant change them. As I know URL does not allow white spaces so I have encoded them with %20 but I think repo-browser of SVN does not follow this convention like any other normal browser like chrome etc. so I am getting

```
Error code 500, Internal Server Error
```

I have seen this question [How can i use SVN as Maven Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443895/how-can-i-use-svn-as-maven-repository) and followed the same steps but it din't work. Please do not mark this as duplicate. 
Kindly help. If anyone have done the same thing , Kindly share the code because I am not able to find any example of usage of SVN with maven.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I will agree that SVN is not designed for this, better not use it this way, use Nexus.

Anyway, can you do

```
svn ls http://SVNUsername:SVNPassword@BaseURL/Proj_U%20Code/Source%20Code/Jars
```

and

```
svn ls "http://SVNUsername:SVNPassword@BaseURL/Proj_U Code/Source Code/Jars"  here with spaces
```

Can you post both the outputs(if different)?